# XSLT - adding node by analyzing text string

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xml file that generate after comparing two xml files.. It looks this this,

```
<doc>
    <para><change flag="start"/><content>changed text</content><change flag="end"/> para text</para> <!--considerd as a change-->
    <para><change flag="start"/><content>changed <t/>text</content><change flag="end"/> para text</para><!--considerd as a change-->
    <para><change flag="start"/>​<content>(1)</content><change flag="end"/> para text</para><!--not considerd as a change-->
    <para><change flag="start"/>​<content>i.</content><change flag="end"/> para text</para><!--not considerd as a change-->
    <para><change flag="start"/>​<content>•</content><change flag="end"/> para text</para><!--not considerd as a change-->
    <para><change flag="start"/><content>​  </content><change flag="end"/> para text</para><!--not considerd as a change-->
    <para><change flag="start"/><content>(1) this is a <t/> numberd list</content><change flag="end"/> para text</para><!--considerd as a change-->
    <para><change flag="start"/>​<content>• this is a <t/> bullet list</content><change flag="end"/>para text</para><!--considerd as a change-->
</doc>
```

here `<change>` element shows the differences of two files and changed content is shown between `<change flag="start"/>​` and `<change flag="end"/>`elements.

what my requirement is transform this to a html. and the content between `<change flag="start"/>​` and `<change flag="end"/>` (differences from the two xml files) should be covered with `<CH>` elements.

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <p><CH>changed text</CH>para text</p>  
      <p><CH>changed text</CH>para text</p>
      <p>​<CH>(1)</CH>para text</p>
      <p>​<CH>i.</CH>para text</p>
      <p>​<CH>•</CH>para text</p>
      <p><CH>​  </CH>para text</p>
      <p><CH>(1) this is a  numberd list</CH>para text</p>
      <p>​<CH>• this is a  bullet list</CH>para text</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

But the problem here is `<change flag="start"/>​` and `<change flag="end"/>` are added for bullets, list numbers and for some whitespaces. eventhout those are changes when comparing the xml files for html representation those should not be considered as change.

So my real expected html output is,

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <p><CH>changed text</CH> para text</p>  
      <p><CH>changed text</CH> para text</p>
      <p>​(1) para text</p>
      <p>​(a) para text</p>
      <p>​• para text</p>
      <p>​  para text</p>
      <p><CH>(1) this is a  numberd list</CH> para text</p>
      <p>​<CH>• this is a  bullet list</CH> para text</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

I've written the following xslt to do this task,

```
<xsl:template match="doc">
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="para">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="*[preceding-sibling::change[@flag='start'] and following-sibling::change[@flag = 'end']]
        [matches(.,$list.mapping/map/@numerator-regex)]">
        <CH>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </CH>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:variable name="list.mapping" as="element()*">
    <map numerator-regex="^\(\d\)"/>
    <map numerator-regex="^\(\d\d\)"/>
    <map numerator-regex="^\d\)"/>
    <map numerator-regex="^\d\."/>
    <map numerator-regex="^\([A-Za-z]\.\)"/>
    <map numerator-regex="^•"/>
    <map numerator-regex="^*"/>
</xsl:variable>


    <xsl:template match="content">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
```

But this is now work as expected.. Can any one suggest me how can I do this, specially how can I eliminate to adding  tags to following scenarios,

- bullets (•) [bullet contain between `<change flag="start"/>​` and `<change flag="end"/>`]
- list numbers (1), (a) [list number contain between `<change flag="start"/>​` and `<change flag="end"/>`]
- whitespaces [whitespaces contain between `<change flag="start"/>​` and `<change flag="end"/>`]

Comment: How complex can that get, can there be several `change` start/end elements in a single `para` element? And what are the exact criteria for wrapping or not wrapping, why is there one example with a bullet at the start that is wrapped while the other is not wrapped? Can you define a finite, well-defined list of regular expression patterns that match the input to be wrapped?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, yes, it can have several change start/end elements in a single para. if the change is only bullet (not any text within that bullet point), it does not considered as a change. I updated the possible regex in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you need to change your `list.mapping` variable to include the `$` symbol. '^' matches the start of the text, and `$` matches the end of the text. This will stop `^\(\d\)` matching `(1) this is a  numberd list`.

```
<xsl:variable name="list.mapping" as="element()*">
    <map numerator-regex="^\(\d\)$"/>
    <map numerator-regex="^\(\d\d\)$"/>
    <map numerator-regex="^\d\)$"/>
    <map numerator-regex="^\d\.$"/>
    <map numerator-regex="^\([A-Za-z]\.\)$"/>
    <map numerator-regex="^•$"/>
    <map numerator-regex="^\*$"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

As for matching, because of your use of `as="element()*"` this means you should be doing `$list.mapping/@numerator-regex` and not `$list.mapping/map/@numerator-regex`. You should also be checking for things that do not match.

The condition you want is this...

```
[not($list.mapping/@numerator-regex[matches(current(), .)])]
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="doc">
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[preceding-sibling::change[@flag='start'] and following-sibling::change[@flag = 'end']]
        [not($list.mapping/@numerator-regex[matches(current(), .)])]">
        <CH>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </CH>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="list.mapping" as="element()*">
    <map numerator-regex="^\(\d\)$"/>
    <map numerator-regex="^\(\d\d\)$"/>
    <map numerator-regex="^\d\)$"/>
    <map numerator-regex="^\d\.$"/>
    <map numerator-regex="^\([A-Za-z]\.\)$"/>
    <map numerator-regex="^•$"/>
    <map numerator-regex="^\*$"/>
</xsl:variable>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This might not give you the exact output you require, as your input XML may have some hidden unicode characters in that affect things, but it may give you a start.